# Setting up gateway in centos 7

Tags: centos, networking

I am trying to setup my centos 7 device as a gateway router and i am able to ping the same from the client (Centos 7 machine too )

I am getting the below response from the gateway when i try to access google.com

```
traceroute to google.com (216.58.199.174), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  dev (192.168.56.101)  0.277 ms  0.209 ms  0.188 ms
 2  dev (192.168.56.101)  0.152 ms !X  0.354 ms !X  0.324 ms !X
```

I am not sure what does "!X" means? I have checked the `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and guess it set to route the packets.

What i might be missing here ?

Comment: From `man traceroute`: "!X (communication administratively prohibited)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

!X means "communication administratively prohibited" it should be documented in the man (8) pages.
Since Linux uses UDP for trace-routes, this can originate from a `--reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` rule at the destination.